# difference of size and size-pack of git count-objects -vH

Tags: git

i'm trying to find out the size of my git repo. I quickly found the `git count-objects` command, read its [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-count-objects) and about it elsewhere online but could not find a plain-language and intuitive explanation of what the output elements mean. I'm especially interested in size, size-pack and their difference.

```
git count-objects -vh

count: 343
size: 1.34 MiB
in-pack: 21183
packs: 3
size-pack: 107.51 MiB
prune-packable: 16
garbage: 0
size-garbage: 0 bytes
```

Thanks in advance & best, Flo

Answer (score 1):

For these numbers to make sense, you have to understand the difference between loose objects and objects stored in packs. Git has two ways to store objects in repos and sandboxes:

- packs contain a whole bunch of objects in a single file,
- loose objects are stored one object-per-file.

Packs are more efficient in terms of disk storage, but creating them can be slower, while loose objects are fast to create.

When you are doing operations in Git, like creating commits, it creates loose objects for speed reasons, but every now and again optimizations are done, where unreachable objects might get deleted and loose objects get combined into packs. A fresh clone would normally have just one pack and no loose objects, for example, but a sandbox where you're done a lot of commits might have a bunch of loose objects.

When you look at `.git/objects/` you will see a directory called `pack/` containing packs, and a bunch of directories whose name is a two-digit hex code (e.g., `04/`, `8c/`, `f2/`) for loose objects.

Finally looping around to your question, `count` and `size` are statistics about loose objects, while `in-pack`, `packs` and `size-pack` are statistics about objects stored in packs.

Comment: thanks! is it thus fair to say, packs are compressed objects whereas loose objects are not? and is the the sum of `size` and `size-pack` the total size of the repo?